# dump() only showing top level

Tags: twig, dump, symfony5

In Twig-Templates in a Symfony 5.4 project (Twig is 3.4.3) when writing something like

```
{{ dump(my_var) }}
```

or just

```
{{ dump() }}
```

the output is only

```
[project_path]\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:57:
array (size=19)
  more elements...
```

and that's it. No debug info (besides the array's element count in this example) appearing.
What am I missing?

Comment: If you have xdebug enabled, then this could be a configuration issue of xdebug

Comment: @DarkBee I do use xDebug. Would you have any hint on what could be missconfigured?

Comment: @DarkBee yes, it does! Setting the var_display_### values to sth sensible fixed it. Thank you! If you want post this as an answere which I mark as solving this issue then.